# Using the Lagrange multipliers to solve an optimization question

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm having trouble with a question given to us as an extra exercise before our exams. The question states that there is a town that lives near a hill. The height at position $(x,y)$ can be described by the function:

$$H(x,y)=100e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{y^2}{2}+x}$$

where $(x,y)$ are coordinates relative to the center of the city in meters. The major of the city wants to take an aerial photograph using a drone which flies in a circular path of equation $x^2+y^2=4$ and stays at a constant height. What is the minimum height the drone has to fly so that it never hits the hill.

So far i managed to setup the equation

$$L=100e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{y^2}{2}+x} +\lambda(x^2+y^2-4)$$

I differentiated with respect to $x, y,$ and $\lambda$ and got the three equations:

$$(100-25x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{y^2}{2}+x}+2x\lambda =0$$
$$-100ye^{-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{y^2}{2}+x}+2y\lambda = 0$$
$$x^2+y^2-4=0$$

I know that i need to solve these to find my $x$ and $y$ value that will give a minimum $H$, but I don't see how I would do this. The exam is non calculator. Have I made a mistake in my work?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I mistakenly wrote $\frac{x^2}{2}$ instead of $\frac{x^2}{8}$

Comment: I am afraid that there is no such a minimal height. On the "minimal" (zero distance) height the drone hits the surface at some ("optimal") point. All higher options (positive distance) can be reduced by e.g. factor two, thus, not optimal.

Comment: @A.Γ. It sounds to me like you're making a purely "physical" objection: assuming a point-sized drone, there's no minimal height because at the infimum of all possible heights the drone hits the hill. I think that's a rather pedantic criticism. The problem statement has plenty of other silly assumptions...

Comment: @Ian "plus a tolerance" - this is my point. It is impossible to fly on the minimal height. How the problem is stated - it has no solution. It is the same as to minimize $e^x$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Except including that aspect of reality would really require you to take into account other things, like the imperfect flight path of the drone and the finite size of the drone. It's not an unreasonable simplification (though you are right that even the mathematically simplified version of the problem should technically use the word infimum instead of minimum).

Comment: @Ian I am not talking about technical things. My formalization to the problem is: find the shortest distance subject to it is postive (no touching to the surface). The problem has no solution. I mean mathematically. For engineers it may sound pedantic, because one cannot come closer than the distance between nucleons. Good (mathematical) statement: find $\max f(x,y)$ subject to $x^2+y^2=4$. The problem above looks like a bad attempt of a teacher to make a good problem sound "applied", missing an important issue in optimization of existence of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would write $$10e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2-x)}=100e^{-\frac{1}{2}(4-x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $H=100e^{x-2}$, you just need to maximise $x$. Then $x=2$ so $H=100$.

Answer (score 0):

Move lambda terms to the right side and divide the first equation by the second to find $x=\frac43$.

From the third equation you find $y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{20}{9}}$.